# Restiful api using laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I wanna make a rest api in laravel i tried several ways but all of them failed , can anyone help me out with a simple way or just tell me how to post 1 field and retrieve it using api to know how it works! thanks

Comment: If you are using Laravel just to build REST API's then don't use Laravel instead use Lumen. 
Here https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-rest-api-with-lumen/ is an example for Building API using Lumen

Comment: Google you will find many such tutorials